# error execution phase upload-config/kubelet: Error writing Crisocket information for the control-plane node: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes

kubeadm         1.16.2-00
kubectl         1.16.2-00
kubelet         1.16.2-00
kubernetes-cni  0.7.5-00
Docker          19.03.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwXEM.png)

Comment: did you turn off swap?

Comment: Perhaps you could update to 1.17. This GitHub issue might be useful -- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1587

Comment: Yes my swap is off @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: Its not helping us in this senario @BoyanHristov

Comment: Were you following any guides creating this cluster? What is the operating system of the machine that is producing this error?

Comment: yes i am folowing this guide https://larrydevops.com/kubernetes/creating-highly-available-clusters-with-kubeadm-with-external-etcd-nodes/ 

And i am working on ubuntu 18.04  @DawidKruk

Comment: can you run kubeadm init --v=10 and provide the output?

Comment: yes i can provide that @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: can you update your question with the output?

Comment: Sorry @ArghyaSadhu , I scraped the entire setup so i cant provide you the updated output to this query.   Right now i am working on setup with another aproach using kubespray to setup multimaster.